# Carto - Search for point by name and zoom to

Tags: carto, select, zoom, carto-js

I have a map I've put together with Carto. The main layer is a brewery point layer. I want to set up a search box that allows the map reader to search for a brewery by name. I know I can set up a filter that does this. However, the crucial piece is that the map then zooms to the brewery when one is selected. Is this possible using Carto.js?  I'm pretty sure I could do it in Leaflet but wouldn't be able to access the data which is in Carto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to add a searchbox div, such as this one:

```
  <div id="searchbox">
  <input type="text" name="ad" value="" id="ad" size="10" />
  <button type="button" id="searchButton">Search</button>
```

Secondly, you have to build a function that fits the bounds to the geometry of the name you have introduced using CARTO.js, Leaflet and JQuery:

```
$('#searchButton').click(function(){
  input = $( "#ad").val();
  var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'user_name' });
  sql.getBounds("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name ILIKE '" + input + "'").done(function(bounds) {
     map.fitBounds(bounds)
     });
   });
```

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/1e3755a44583058f4b95) you have a working example.